# Generic method for setting string enum converter in EF Core for all entities

Tags: c#, enums, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0, valueconverter

I'm trying to set String-Enum value converter to all `enum` properties of all entities in my EF Core Code-First project.

I can do this manually like this:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Do this for every single enum property in each of the entities
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(e => e.MyEnum).HasConversion<string>();
    }
```

But I'm looking for a generic way of doing this for all properties using an extension method. I tried using the below code, but I'm getting the following error:

> Converter for model type 'object' cannot be used for 'MyEnum'

```
    public static void SetEnumStringConverter(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var properties = modelBuilder?.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(x => x.GetProperties().Where(y => typeof(Enum).IsAssignableFrom(y.ClrType)));
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            property.SetValueConverter(new ValueConverter<object, string>(v => v.ToString(), v => (object)Enum.Parse(property.ClrType, v)));
        }
    }
```

Also tried the following, gives me the same error

```
    property.SetValueConverter(new ValueConverter<Enum, string>(v => v.ToString(), v => Enum.Parse(property.ClrType, v)));
```

Obviously because enum is not an object?

Nevertheless, is there any other way of doing this in a generic way?

Comment: You may be able to accomplish it using reflection. You could find all the model classes (assuming they share a namespace) and then iterate over all of their properties, filter to only properties with an enum type, and then call `modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(e => e.MyEnum).HasConversion<string>();` as a chain of invocations of `MethodInfo`. (Start here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: What happens if you don't box to `object`? Like `new ValueConverter<Enum, string>(v => v.ToString(), v => Enum.Parse(property.ClrType, v))`

Comment: @crgolden yes, I've already tried that, gives me the same error

Comment: @JamesFaix yes, that is what I was trying to do. Just that when I use reflection, I'm not able to use the method `.HasConversion<string>()`, because I get `IMutableProperty` and not `PropertyBuilder`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use [SetProviderClrType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.mutablepropertyextensions.setproviderclrtype?view=efcore-3.1) extension method, e.g.

```
public static void SetEnumStringConverter(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var properties = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
        .SelectMany(e => e.GetProperties())
        .Where(p => (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(p.ClrType) ?? p.ClrType).IsEnum);

    foreach (var property in properties)
       property.SetProviderClrType(typeof(string)); // <--
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, after a little digging, I found a way to achieve this. Though not straightforward, gets the desired result.

```
    public static void SetEnumStringConverter(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder?.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            var entityBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.ClrType);
            foreach (var property in entityType.GetProperties())
            {
                if (typeof(Enum).IsAssignableFrom(property.ClrType))
                {
                    entityBuilder.Property(property.ClrType, property.Name).HasConversion<string>();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```